# dashboard.dart parameter issue

Tags: flutter, dart

In trying to run the Chrome build I receive the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
lib/src/screens/Dashboard.dart:64:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'title'.
                title: Text(
                ^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/bottom_navigation_bar_item.dart:25:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const BottomNavigationBarItem({
```

In the code it's written like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Fryo.shop),
                title: Text(
                  'Store',
                  style: tabLinkStyle,
                )),
```

I'm guessing this has to do with mobile vs. web version, so there may be a parameter I need to add where it overlooks this for the web version.

This is my first Flutter app and the code I'm using is a copy I'm using that is 3 years old, so I'm running into various issues when updating it. This particular issue may be because it was not built with a web version to begin with. Anyhow, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The above is an example. There's a total of 5 title errors, all related to the bottom nav bar. I'm also receiving the following warning "warning: The include file 'package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml' in '/Users/myuser/Documents/Development/shopping_app/analysis_options.yaml' can't be found when analyzing '/Users/myuser/Documents/Development/shopping_app'. (include_file_not_found at [fryo] analysis_options.yaml:10)"

Answer (score 0):

try **label** instead of title.

but only **string** not widget.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Fryo.shop),
                label:'Store',
                ),
```

```
const BottomNavigationBarItem(
{required Widget icon,
String? label,
Widget? activeIcon,
Color? backgroundColor,
String? tooltip}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear.

"No named parameter with the name 'title'", This means  BottomNavigationBarItem has no **title** property

according to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html

you should use **label** property instead.

Comment: That's helpful, however now I get the following error: "lib/src/screens/Dashboard.dart:64:24: Error: The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Text' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' ('/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart').
                label: Text(
                       ^" Does that mean I'm missing a package here? Or that I should rename it String instead of Text?

Comment: Please Check my answer that will help